# EditText Multiline com linhas separadas por traços

Tags: java, android, edittext

Tudo bem?

Gostaria que vocês me ajudassem em uma coisa:
Eu gostaria de ter um EditText com Multilines divididas em linhas.

O que eu quero dizer é o seguinte: 
Quando criamos um EditText multiline (vamos colocar como exemplo um multiline com 4 linhas), ele deixa aquela traço embaixo para digitar lá em baixo na quarta linha, e todas as outras 3 linhas de cima ficam um espaço em branco.
Eu gostaria de ter 4 desses traços, um para cada linha do meu multiline, como se fossem 4 EditText um embaixo do outro.

Pensei em fazer exatamente como disse acima, usar 4 EditText e depois na hora de enviar os dados fazer: EditText1 + EditText2 + EditText3 + EditText4; porém, não sei como ficaria a questão de chegar no final do EditText1 e já descer para o 2 automaticamente.

Se alguem tiver uma sugestão, solução ou caso tenha ficado alguma dúvida, só mandar mensagem. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia tenta criar um componente que extensa de EditText e sobreescreva o onDraw para desenhas as linhas, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
public class LinedEditText extends EditText {
    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;

    // we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(R.color.edit_note_line); //SET YOUR OWN COLOR HERE
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //int count = getLineCount();

        int height = getHeight();
        int line_height = getLineHeight();

        int count = height / line_height;

        if (getLineCount() > count)
            count = getLineCount();//for long text with scrolling

        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);//first line

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
            baseline += getLineHeight();//next line
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

no seu xml ao invés de usar o EditText usa com.exemplo.seupacote.LinedEditText

Esta sugestão foi retirado [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972388/drawing-multiple-lines-in-edittext-e-g-notepad/6111460#6111460).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá amigo. Primeiramente obrigado pela ajuda. Eu criei essa classe que você disse "LinedEditText", e fui no xml da minha activity e mudei o EditText para "com.exemplo.meupacote.LinedEditText" como vc me sugeriu, porém, aparece alguns erros na pré-visualização: "The following classes could not be found". E a classe já foi criada, vc sabe como resolver isso? Obrigado.

Comment: Amigo, mil desculpas. Estava com erro mais eu  consegui arrumar dando "build" no projeto. Agora está do jeito que eu queria. Ainda não testei, mais já ficou da forma que eu queria. Muito obrigado pela ajuda...vou dar o teste final aqui e deixou o comentário final pra finalizar o tópico. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente cara. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Beleza, marca a resposta como resposta certa ^^ heheh obrigado